# I need to write a program which calculates the number of hours a person has used a machine but I can not go over 23:59:59

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code so far. I need to write a program which prints the billing information for a machine which is hired out.

```
hours = 23
minutes = 81
seconds = 0

seconds_in_minute = 60
seconds_in_hour = 3600

final_seconds = seconds % 60
final_seconds2 = ((2 - len(str(final_seconds))) * "0") + str(final_seconds)
extra_minutes = int(seconds / 60)
final_minutes = (minutes + extra_minutes) % 60
final_minutes2 = ((2 - len(str(final_minutes))) * "0") + str(final_minutes)
extra_hours = int(minutes / 60)
final_hours = (hours + extra_hours)
final_hours2 = ((2 - len(str(final_hours))) * "0") + str(final_hours)

cost_for_seconds = 2
cost_for_seconds_in_full_minute = 1.6
cost_for_seconds_in_full_hour = 1.2
seconds_cost = cost_for_seconds * final_seconds
minutes_cost = cost_for_seconds_in_full_minute * (final_minutes * seconds_in_minute)
hours_cost = cost_for_seconds_in_full_hour * (final_hours * seconds_in_hour)

cost_for_seconds = 2
cost_for_seconds_in_full_minute = 1.6
cost_for_seconds_in_full_hour = 1.2
seconds_cost = cost_for_seconds * final_seconds
minutes_cost = cost_for_seconds_in_full_minute * (final_minutes * seconds_in_minute)
hours_cost = cost_for_seconds_in_full_hour * (final_hours * seconds_in_hour)


print("hours =", hours)
print("minutes =", minutes)
print("seconds =", seconds)
print("=" * 35)
print(" ", " ", "Total time: ", final_hours2, ":", final_minutes2, ":", final_seconds2 , sep = "")
print(" ", " ", "Cost: ", "$", int(seconds_cost + minutes_cost + hours_cost), sep = "")
print("=" * 35)
```

Which produces the output of

```
hours = 23
minutes = 81
seconds = 0
===================================
  Total time: 24:21:00
  Cost: $101376
===================================
```

Problem is I need it to be in the format 00:21:00

I need it so that the cost is still the same, but the hours display is never 24 hours or over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the modulo operation.

After calculating `final_hours`, you need to do :

`final_hours = final_hours % 24`

Your final hours will always be a value beetween 0 and 23

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thank you very much. I feel pretty stupid.

Comment: No problem ;) Next time you will remember. "One learns by making mistakes"

Answer (score 0):

Just add a day for every 24 hours:

Here is a code snippet that will normalize `seconds, minutes, hours, days`:

```
extra_minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
extra_hours, minutes = divmod(minutes + extra_minutes, 60) 
extra_days, hours = divmod(hours + extra_hours, 24) 
days += extra_days
```

and here is a way to make a string with time in HH:MM:SS zero-padded format:

```
"{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Hope it helps.